# Clangs C++ Module TS support: How to tell clang++ where to find the module file?

Tags: c++, clang++

In his [talk](https://youtu.be/h1E-XyxqJRE?t=45m15s) at CppCon, Richard Smith mentioned that even though the Module TS support is currently work in progress, it can already be used. So I build clang 4.0 from svn and tried it on a very simple example. In my `myclass.cppm` file I defined a simple wrapper for an `int`

```
 module myclass;

 export class MyClass {
 public:
     MyClass (int i) 
          : _i{i} {}

     int get() {
          return _i;
     }
 private:
     int _i;
 };
```

and my `main.cpp` just creates one instance of that class and outputs its held `int` to `std::cout`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
import myclass;

int main(int, char**) {
    MyClass three{3};
    std::cout << std::to_string(three.get()) << std::endl;
}
```

Then I tried to compile it via `clang++ -std=c++1z -fmodules-ts main.cpp` and with `clang++ -std=c++1z -fmodules-ts myclass.cppm main.cpp` but that doesn`t work and I get the same error message in both cases:

```
main.cpp:3:8: fatal error: module 'myclass' not found
import test.myclass;
~~~~~~~^~~~
1 error generated.
```

Unfortunately I have not been able to find documentation for `-fmodules-ts`. Does someone know how I can get clang++ to compile my simple example?

Answer (score 3):

You can compile it as follows:

```
clang++ -std=c++1z -fmodules-ts --precompile -o myclass.pcm myclass.cppm 
clang++ -std=c++1z -fmodules-ts -fmodule-file=myclass.pcm -o modules_test main.cpp
```

However, this can't be how it's meant to work since you'd manually need to encode the dependency hierarchy of your modules in the calls to the compiler; I'd be very interested in the correct answer to this question :-).

Comment: I'm not so sure about that, it might be intentional to better guide build systems what they need to recompile.

Comment: But how does the build system know the order in which to compile things? Also, the build system would need to accumulate modules: If module X depends on modules A and B and module A depends on module C, it would need to build the following command line:

Comment: clang++ -std=c++1z -fmodules-ts --precompile -o X.pcm -fmodule-file=A.pcm -fmodule-file=B.pcm -fmodule-file=C.pcm X.cppm

This doesn't seem to be the way to go. There must be some kind of lookup mechanism. Or, at least, the compiler should accept an un-ordered list of all source files...

Comment: By the way: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#compilation-model says: "The binary representation of modules is automatically generated by the compiler on an as-needed basis." - This is exactly what I mean here and what we need to somehow enable ;)

Comment: Modules can never have circular dependencies. Clang just needs to know where it can find prebuilt modules. Pass `-fprebuilt-module-path=...` and away you go. Note, however, that clang will never rebuild a prebuilt module, so sometimes you need to compile the module itself -- to produce an object file to pass to the linker. That's what the `-fmodule-file=...` business is for.

Answer (score 0):

**-fprebuilt-module-path** works even though it fires a warning: "argument unused during compilation: '-fprebuilt-module-path=.'"

The complete command was:

```
clang++-4.0 -std=c++1z -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. -o modules_test main.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

as of 27th of December, 2017 I have checked out the latest llvm branch, built it on my macbook and then eexecuted the following:

`./../bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -fmodules-ts --precompile  -o myclass.pcm myclass.cppm
./../bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -c myclass.pcm -o myclass.o
./../bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. -o main main.cpp hello.o`

and tada, worked prefectly without any warnings or errors.