# C++ modules using clang

Tags: c++, module, clang, c++-modules

[As it looks like](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) Clang is providing support for the modules TS. I [tried this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307657/how-do-i-use-c-modules-in-clang) using Clang, compiled from SVN (trunk), and it worked as expected.

I want to take it to the next step wrapping the [catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) library in to a module.

I tried to declare a `module.modulemap` in this way:

```
module Catch {
  header "catch/catch.hpp"
  export *
}
```

and `main.cpp` containing:

```
import Catch;

int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
{
  int result = Catch::Session().run(argc, argv);
  return result;
}
```

The [compilation model](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#compilation-model) states that "*the binary representation of modules is automatically generated by the compiler on an as-needed basis.*"

Compiling `main.cpp` using `clang-4.0 -std=c++1z -fmodules-ts main.cpp` I get:

```
main.cpp:1:8: fatal error: module 'Catch' not found
import Catch;
~~~~~~~^~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Any idea how it could be solved?

Comment: Try maybe to specify the modules file with `-fmodule-file=<path>` (clang should do that automatically, but we're debugging).

Comment: @ShmuelH. using that option Clang reports: fatal error:
`file 'module.modulemap' is not a valid precompiled module file.`

Comment: My mistake, it's `-fmodule-map-file`.

Comment: Clang is still complaining with `fatal error: module 'Catch' is needed but has not been provided, and implicit use of module files is disabled`
I tried to play with some flags but it didn't work

Comment: @ShmuelH. I also need to provide `-fmodules-ts` to enable modules, in contrast with `-fmodules` provided by the clang documentation. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is described on the documentation page you refer to (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) is actually not the module TS.

It's the non-standard hack of clang to leverage the precompiled headers infrastructure to make them modularly reusable. The trick is simply to allow precompiled headers to be loaded in any order, or even loaded after having already parsed some code. That's based on the assumption that previously parsed/loaded code shouldn't have any side effect of further precompiled code. Other more traditional PCH handlings can be considered too much pedantic in this regard and end up being far less flexible (i.e. far less modular) in that they require either one monolithic PCH that needs the be the first thing loaded (e.g. MSVC), or a chain of PCH with a fixed ordering (GCC).

The objective-C language is augmented with an `@import` keyword that effectively "include" all the files listed in the corresponding `module.modulemap` file (which actually means generating and/or loading the corresponding PCH file).

When the objective-C extension is not enabled, there's no `import` keyword, but you still have another trick in place: it intercepts `#include` preprocessor directives so that they instead "include" all the files listed in the corresponding `module.modulemap` file (which, again, actually means generating and/or loading the corresponding PCH file).

There are no `module` and `export` keywords (these only appear in `module.modulemap` files); everything is exported.

This modular-PCH hack is enabled with the `-fmodules` compiler flag.

It's valuable in that it helps with speeding up the build process on large codebases, and it also allows lazily preparing the transition of an old codebase towards the future modular structure, without requiring an instant rewrite of the whole world.

I doubt that it's being much used in production, apart from a few very-involved companies like google, which has knowable clang developers who can fix the bugs if needed.

To actually make your code work with this system, you need to either:

- edit your `main.cpp` to use `@import Catch;` and use the following command to compile `clang++ -fmodules -I . -xobjective-c++ main.cpp`
- edit you `main.cpp` to use `#include "catch/catch.hpp"` and use the following command to compile `clang++ -fmodules main.cpp`

With the first usage, notice the importance of correctly setting the preprocessor include paths with `-I` since the system will under the hood lookup for your `module.modulemap` files on the preprocessor paths, even if you don't write any `#include` directive in your code.

Technically, you can verify that the module system was effectively enabled by looking at the generated PCH files under the `/tmp/org.llvm.clang.$USER/ModuleCache/` dir, as `Catch-$HASHSUM.pcm`. You may end up with several ones for the same module since the PCH are dependent (amgonst other things) on the compiler options that were used (e.g. the objective-C support in the above example). Clang manages this cache dir by itself; it even removes old unused files (anyway `/tmp/` is also wiped out during boot).

As you found out, the new `-fmodules-ts` compiler flag effectively asks for the future module TS support we're all looking for. Note that it's hardly usable currently.

A question on how to use it was already asked and answered: [Clangs C++ Module TS support: How to tell clang++ where to find the module file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818600/clangs-c-module-ts-support-how-to-tell-clang-where-to-find-the-module-file)